# Prevent react-native-map from re-rendering after states change [Reat-Native]

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

In my app I'm using react-native-maps and every time states change the map reloads. How can I avoid this behaviour? I've tried to use React.memo but it seems to don't work.

[update]
I've tried to put the MapView directly inside the return and it doesn't reload, why?

Feel free to link me everything. Here's my code:

[functional component]

```
  const MapViewContainer = () => {
    return (
      <MapView
        initialRegion={initialRegion}
        provider="google"
        ref={mapRef}
        style={styles.map}
      >
        {/* {items.map((item, index) => {
          return <Marker {...{ item, index }} />;
        })} */}
      </MapView>
    );
  };

const MemorizeMap = React.memo(MapViewContainer, areEqual);

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <MemorizeMap />
      <Button
        title="update"
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onPress={() => {
          setOpacity(0);
        }}
      />
    </View>
```

Comment: Does the markers need to update when the state changes, or should they just be rendered once?

Comment: markers doesn't matter, the problem is when I place the map in return it's different from placing it in a function and then call it in return.